# Nestable.js funciona a nivel de logica pero no visualmente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy usando *Nestable.js* para hacer una lista de productos con subproductos para que se visualice en forma de árbol. No tengo ningún error en consola y no veo donde puede estar mi error, pero una vez configurado todo, la lista aparece así:

- Producto
- Subproducto

Cuando debería salir así:

1. Producto

   1. Subproducto

Esta es al estructura que tengo para la lista:

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable2">
<ol class="dd-list>
    <li class="dd-item>
     <div class="dd-handle>Producto 1 </div>
         <ol class="dd-list>
             <li class="dd-item>
                 <div class="dd-handle>Subproducto 1 </div>
             </li>
          </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Y el js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nestable2').nestable();
});
```

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que veo es que las etiquetas de las clases están mal cerradas, no sé si es un artefacto del código que has copiado, pero a mi me funciona corrigiendo este detalle. Te dejo un ejemplo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#nestable2').nestable();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Nestable/2012-10-15/jquery.nestable.js"></script>

<div class="dd" id="nestable2">
    <ol class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item">
         <div class="dd-handle">Producto 1 </div>
             <ol class="dd-list">
                 <li class="dd-item">
                     <div class="dd-handle">Subproducto 1 </div>
                 </li>
              </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
    </div>
```

Comment: Esas comillas se me habian pasado al copiarlo. Por lo demas esta igual.

Comment: Prueba a pasarle nestable con la version de cdn que he usado en el ejemplo para ver si puede ser un problema del archivo, no sé si lo tienes en tu proyecto o lo traes por cdn.

Comment: Lo he probado y continua igual. Puede ser por la version de jquery? Yo estoy usando jquery 3.1.1. Si no es eso yo ya no se que mas hacer.

Comment: Le acabo de cambiar al ejemplo la versión de jquery para comprobarlo y sigue funcionando. Es posible que tengas otro JavaScript que este interfiriendo con nestable? Si es el caso quita el resto de JavaScript del documento para probarlo y luego lo vas añadiendo.